# Jan 2012 C++11 Working Draft "Source" Format?

Tags: c++, c++11

The Jan 2012 working draft of the C++ standard is here in PDF form:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Is it publicly known what source format and process/tools are used to produce this PDF?

Are those source files also publicly available?

Is the document content available in any other format than PDF?

Comment: I wonder if there is a newer version of the draft available?

Comment: @piokuc There is: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LaTeX sources are on [GitHub](http://github.com/cplusplus/draft) along with instructions for building them.